# Почему возвращает Ресурс №4

Tags: php, mysql

Почему функция db_connect() возвращает Ресурс №4
Warning: mysql_close(): 4 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource

```
require_once('common_use.php');
$connect_db = db_connect();

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/views/home.html';

mysql_close($connect_db) or die(mysql_error());
```

Файл сommon_use.php

```
  function db_connect(){
    $server = 'localhost'; 
    $username = 'root'; 
    $password = '';
    $dbname = 'newster';
    $link = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
        if (!$link) {
            die('Невозможно соединиться с базой данных: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname);
        if (!$db_selected) {
            die ('Невозможно выбрать базу данных: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    return $link;
}
```

Comment: можешь в кавычки хотябы взять или в цитату, что у тебя выдает.

Да и вопрос у тебя почему ошибку дает, или откуда в коде ошибки "Ресурс №4" ?

Comment: Если у вы работаете только с одной БД, то можно и не указывать дескриптор. В этом случае, закрывается последнее открытое/текущее соединение.

P.S. И пора бы на PDO переходить ;)

Comment: Возможно $connect_db где-то переопределяется. Попробуйте var_dump($connect_db) перед функцией mysql_close();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот Разбери лучше это:

```
class db {
    static $con;

    public static function connect() {
        $dbData = parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.ini');

        self::$con = mysql_connect($dbData['host'],$dbData['user'],$dbData['pass']);
        $db = mysql_select_db($dbData['db']);
        if ((!self::$con) || (!$db))
            return 0;
        else return 1;
    }

    public static function deconnect() {
        if( !isset( self::$con ) ) return;
        mysql_close( self::$con );
    }

}
```

Comment: Сейчас народ набежит и закидает вас pdo. )

Comment: не, ну автор использует mysql_ и поэтому решил помочь, чем просит) А вообще ему уже говорили на счёт mysql_